# Can I have Multiple SVG images in a single file?

Tags: css, html, svg

Instead of doing the following:

```
<html>
<body>
  <embed src="circle.svg" type="image/svg+xml" /> 
  <embed src="square.svg" type="image/svg+xml" /> 
  <embed src="triangle.svg" type="image/svg+xml" />  
</body>
</html>
```

I would prever to do something like this

```
<html>
<body>
<embed src="shapes.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="circle" /> 
<embed src="shapes.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="square" /> 
<embed src="shapes.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="triangle" />  
</body>
</html>
```

with a svg file that may look something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" >

  <svg id="circle">
    <circle cx="100" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black"
    stroke-width="2" fill="red" />
  </svg> 

  <svg id="square">
    <rect width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:1;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
  </svg>

  <svg id="triangle">
    <line x1="50" y1="0" x2="0" y2="50" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
    <line x1="50" y1="0" x2="100" y2="50" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
    <line x1="0" y1="50" x2="100" y2="50" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
  </svg>
</svg>
```

It seems as an SVG is just XML I should be able to store all my images in a single file that downloades a single time and is used throughout the site.

Comment: If your intent is to have only "triangle" visible when you invoke it like `<embed src="shapes.svg#triangle" type="image/svg+xml" />`, you'll have to wait for browsers to catch up because support just isn't there yet:  http://simurai.com/post/20251013889/svg-stacks.  You can, however, treat it like any ordinary spritemap.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562136/merging-multiple-svg-files-into-one/14563888#14563888?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can only have a single root node in an html document. Nevertheless there are various ways to achieve what you want.

One way is [SVG Stacks](http://simurai.com/post/20251013889/svg-stacks) which works by having all the drawings on top of each other and then just displaying the one you want to see using CSS.

Another way might be to have a shapes.svg like this with all the drawings in different places

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">

  <g transform="translate(0,0)">
    <circle cx="100" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="red" />
  </g>

  <g transform="translate(0,200)">
    <rect width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:1;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(0,400)">
    <line x1="50" y1="0" x2="0" y2="50" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
    <line x1="50" y1="0" x2="100" y2="50" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
    <line x1="0" y1="50" x2="100" y2="50" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

And then use svgView to show just the bits you want.

```
<html>
<body>
<embed src="shapes.svg#svgView(viewBox(50,0,100,100))" style="width:100px;        height:100px" type="image/svg+xml" />
<embed src="shapes.svg#svgView(viewBox(0,200,100,100))" style="width:100px;height:100px" type="image/svg+xml"/> 
<embed src="shapes.svg#svgView(viewBox(0,400,100,100))" style="width:100px;height:100px" type="image/svg+xml"/>  
</body>
</html>
```

All of these do mean though that you use more memory in the UA as the whole svg file is loaded 3 times and you just see a part of it each time.

Comment: The SVG file is loaded each time?  Does it load every time you use the embed statement?

Comment: It won't fetch it 3 times, it will create the complete DOM 3 times though.

Comment: I saw a nice example of this today which made me revisit this post.  It is basically using this same solution. https://codepen.io/NielsOeltjen/pen/uCgLI

Comment: I went ahead and accepted the answer, though I still hold out hope for better days ahead with .svg files.

Answer (score 12):

**Reference:**

```
<svg alt="">
    <use xlink:href="shapes.svg#circle"></use>
</svg>
<svg alt="">
    <use xlink:href="shapes.svg#square"></use>
</svg>
<svg alt="">
    <use xlink:href="shapes.svg#triangle"></use>
</svg>
```

**shapes.svg:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <symbol id="circle">
        <circle cx="100" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="red" />
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="square">
        <rect width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:1;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
    </symbol>
    <symbol id="triangle">
        <line x1="50" y1="0" x2="0" y2="50" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
        <line x1="50" y1="0" x2="100" y2="50" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
        <line x1="0" y1="50" x2="100" y2="50" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
    </symbol>
</svg>
```

Comment: Has anyone made this example work?  I see 4 upvotes, but could not get it working myself.

Comment: Yes. What is the issue your having?

Comment: @JeremyA.West Added XML version, encoding, and SVG Doctype for the external file. This should mainly affect Safari I believe. Let me know if you still run into problems or this fixes it. Thanks.

Comment: As of 2023 this method works only partially.
E.g., do not work linear gradients in Safari Mobile 12.2.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, but XML documents need a single root node.  Yours has *three*.  Try wrapping the three nodes in an svg element and move the namespace and version number to it.  Seems to validate via http://validator.w3.org/check

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <svg id="circle">
      <circle cx="100" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black"
      stroke-width="2" fill="red" />
    </svg> 

    <svg id="square">
      <rect width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:1;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
    </svg>

    <svg id="triangle">
      <line x1="50" y1="0" x2="0" y2="50" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
      <line x1="50" y1="0" x2="100" y2="50" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
      <line x1="0" y1="50" x2="100" y2="50" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
    </svg>
</svg>
```

Comment: I won't swear that's the best solution, just the first that came to mind.  All XML documents must have *one* root node.

Answer (score 0):

- I couldn't get the answers to work as per other comments (Nov' 2023). So, updated the code.

In a file called **shapes.svg** insert the following XML containing SVG symbol tags:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve">  
        <symbol id="circle">
            <circle cx="100" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="2" fill="red" />
        </symbol>
        <symbol id="square">
            <rect width="100" height="1000px" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:10px;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
        </symbol>
        <symbol id="triangle">
            <line x1="50" y1="0" x2="0" y2="50" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
            <line x1="50" y1="0" x2="100" y2="50" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
            <line x1="0" y1="50" x2="100" y2="50" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
        </symbol>
    </svg>
```

- In a file **index.html** reference the individual SVG symbol as follows:

.

```
<html>
    <body style="background-color:yellow;">
        <svg>
            <use xlink:href="shapes.svg#circle"></use>
        </svg>
        <svg>
            <use xlink:href="shapes.svg#square"></use>
        </svg>
        <svg>
            <use xlink:href="shapes.svg#triangle"></use>
        </svg>      
    </body>
</html>
```