# How can I change http:// linked images in Inkscape 0.92 to embedded ones?

Tags: image, http, svg, inkscape

I'm using Inkscape 0.92 for OS X from the official download page (https://inkscape.org/en/release/0.92.2/mac-os-x/), but I can't seem to get it to load images that have been included using http, for instance, an SVG like this

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="950" height="717">
<image width="120" height="120" preserveAspectRatio="none"
 xlink:href="https://media.inkscape.org/media/cms_page_media/328/Inkscape_Logo2.png"/>
</svg>
```

I would like to change these images to embedded ones, but when I try Extensions->Images->Embed Images, I get

> No xlink:href or sodipodi:absref attributes found, or they do not point to an existing file! Unable to embed image.
>   Sorry we could not locate /media/cms_page_media/328/Inkscape_Logo2.png

Which implies to me that Inkscape cannot deal with http:// urls (i.e. get images from the internet)

Is there any way to enable this?

Comment: See bug reports: https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/1364663 (While one comment there says loading a file with 'inkscape http://...` on the CL works, I cannot confirm that with v0.92/Linux) and https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/723627

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I think it's this one: https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/723627. It would be good to add this to the documentation somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a perl script which should do an inline-replace of linked jpg files in an svg with an embedded base64 encoded version:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;
use MIME::Base64;
our $^I=''; # see perlvar(1)
while(<>){
    s|(xlink:href=)(["'])(https?:[\w/.]+\.jpg)\g2|$1.$2."data:image/jpg;base64,".encode_base64(get($3), "").$2|eg; #embed jpgs
    print;
}
```