# how to read SVG files and combine them all in one using r

Tags: r, svg

I have 7 different figures saved as SVG format.
I would like to combine them all in one using R.
Would please show me how to do?
I have see the link below but its not in r
[Merging multiple SVG files into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562136/merging-multiple-svg-files-into-one)

Best,
Amare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read the svg files, convert them into ggplot2 objects and use patchwork operator e.g. `|` to stack them vertically:

```
library(patchwork)
library(magick)

(
  image_read("circle.svg") |> image_ggplot() |
  image_read("rect.svg") |> image_ggplot()
)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know if something like this could work with base r and like layout()?  Looks like the Magick package can do it its own way. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html

Comment: Yes, there is the function `magick::image_append` see [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html#Combining)